# How do I get the latest message in an SNS Topic?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

Using AWS CLI, how do I get the latest message in an SNS topic?

Specifically I would like to view this SNS topic, which is used by AWS to inform users of changes to IP ranges of their services:

```
arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:806199016981:AmazonIpSpaceChanged
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SNS does not support that. You can subscribe to a topic and get all future notifications pushed to you. There is no support for querying historical messages.